# Mozilla Firefox after update from 57.0.x to 59.0.x UI fonts are blurry. How to fix?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, browser, fonts

Recently my Firefox on Win10 was automatically updated to 59.0.x from 57.0.x and after that UI fonts (not HTML pages) became blurry. HTML pages displayed correctly, because at `about:config` setting `gfx.canvas.azure.backends` and `gfx.content.azure.backends` are set to `direct2d1.1,cairo,skia` (not to `direct2d1.1,skia,cairo`). But now the problem with Firefox UI fonts - menus, text fields, etc. - they are blurry. Here are the screenshots:

**FF 57.0.x - UI fonts ok**
[image]

**FF 59.0.x - UI fonts blurry**
[image]

At the moment downgraded to 57.0.x version. Is there some way to fix these blurry fonts?

Comment: To clarify, Firefox 59 is currently a [Beta version](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/) of the web browser.  The most recent stable version is 58.0.1... have you tried that one?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it - the same. I noticed another problem - fonts are changing form blurry to normal when I moving the mouse over them (for example over page tabs) - it happens when hardware acceleration is turned off (which I prefer) and cairo rendering is preferred instead of skia. On FF 57 I see no problems.

Answer (score 1):

This bug (?) appeared in 58.x, in 57.x old font rendering (Cairo) works fine for both websites and FF UI.

Solution:

Enable `gfx.text.disable-aa` in about:config.

AA on:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2gKh.png

AA off:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibh6L.png

Works for me, FF 63.0.1 x64, Win7 x64, ClearType disabled. Will test on Win10 too.

OFC with ClearType disabled in Windows and AA disabled in Firefox, some websites' fonts will be "too thin":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOpvR.png

So you have to use either some font switcher (Stylus for example) or change fonts via userChrome.css. Font changed to good old Arial:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUjuk.png

It's still not a perfect solution (pre-58.x text AA has been working fine with Cairo), but it gets the job done.

Comment: Still, can not reach desired performance using FF 63  - perhaps due to `cairo` is not supported starting from FF 58? Downgraded to FF 57 again..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like as of v75.0 Firefox no longer supports old rendering (Cairo). The fix I've described above stopped working, so I've checked about:config.

And the "cairo" setting is missing entirely:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxkOP.jpg

Old rendering still works in Waterfox (both Classic and Current), even with AA on. Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately?), WF is based on older source code (Classic: v56.0, Current: v6something).

So, if you want an old FF rendering engine, FF is no longer an option.